# gawk split on pattern

Tags: regex, text-processing, gawk

I am trying to split a string by pattern.
The strings looks like this

```
"Table 4. Kings County" 

"Table 984. Los Angles County"
```

Desired array would be

```
"Table 4","Kings","County"
"Table 984","Los Angles","County"
```

I tried something like this

```
echo "Table 4. Kings County"  | gawk '{patsplit($0,a,/Table [[:digit:]]./s); print a[1]}'
```

But doesn't really work

Comment: `design-patterns` - Please don't use this tag on questions about text pattern matching. [Tag Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/design-patterns/info)

Comment: didn't realize I did that. Must of been a mistake.

Comment: You mean "county"?  The pattern is Table [number]. County Name county

Comment: The `gawk` tag is visited by far fewer people far less often than the `awk` tag so to get more people looking at your question with a view to helping you, tag your awk questions with `awk`, optionally add a `gawk` tag if you like, and state in your question that you're using gawk.

Answer (score 1):

***gawk*** solution with `gensub` function:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/(Table [0-9]+)\. (.*) (County)/,"\\1\042,\042\\2\042,\042\\3","g",$0); print $0}' file
```

The output:

```
"Table 4","Kings","County" 
"Table 984","Los Angles","County"
```

---

> ***gensub()*** provides an additional feature that is not available in sub() or *gsub()*: the ability to specify components of a regexp in
>   the replacement text. This is done by using parentheses in the regexp
>   to mark the components and then specifying ‘*\N*’ in the replacement
>   text, where *N* is a digit from 1 to 9.

`\042` - octal code of double quote `"`

---

To consider replacement up to `County` word use the following additional approach:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/(Table [0-9]+)\. (.*) (County).*/,"\\1\042,\042\\2\042,\042\\3\042","g",$0); print $0}' file
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. How can I get only up to county? Table 4 Kinds County blah blah blah. I only want to get content up to "county"

Comment: @NinjaGaiden, To consider replacement up to `County` word use my additional approach

Answer (score 0):

As currently shown, the problem seems a good match to sed's capabilities:

```
$ sed -E 's/([[:digit:]])[.] */\1","/; s/ *(County") *$/","\1/' file
"Table 4","Kings","County"
"Table 984","Los Angles","County"
```

How it works:

- `s/([[:digit:]])[.] */\1","/`

  This substitution puts the `"."` after the table number
- `s/ *(County") *$/","\1/`

  This substitution puts the `","` before the final `County`.

Comment: Thanks. Need it in awk because I am doing other processing in awk

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/\. /,"\",\"")sub(/ C/,"\",\"C"); $0=$0}NF=NF' file

"Table 4","Kings","County"
"Table 984","Los Angles","County"
```

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(Table [0-9]+)\. (.*) (County)/\1","\2","\3/'
```